# Read rows from text file, take more lines if value matches

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, filestream

I have a text file that has several thousand rows. Each row is a student and test scores for various tests. Not all students have the same number of tests (ie rows). I need to break the file up into smaller chunks, but I don't want to break up any group of student scores. No sorting is necessary as the main file is already sorted, but we sort it for good measure.

Lets say I want the chunk to have at least 5 rows, but if the 6th row is the same student as the 5th row, then add the 6th row to the chunk. And so on, until the student changes.

Then, start a new chunk (with the headers, but that part is easy) until the end of the original file is reached.

I'm fine with either linq or FileStream, once I have each chunk I will be loading it into an app via an API.

Here is a simplified sample of the main file:

```
STUDENT_ID    TEST    SCORE
000001          A       10
000001          B       10
000001          C       10
000001          D       10
000002          A       10
000002          B       10
000002          C       10
000002          D       10
000003          A       10
000003          B       10
000004          C       10
000004          D       10
000004          E       10
000004          F       10
```

So, the first chunk would look like:

```
STUDENT_ID    TEST    SCORE
000001          A       10
000001          B       10
000001          C       10
000001          D       10
000002          A       10
000002          B       10
000002          C       10
000002          D       10
```

So far I've done one While loop that uses a constant "rowsToTake" = 5, a substring(0, 6) that compares the STUDENT_ID of the 5th row taken, and a "currentPosition" that increments on each take. I lost momentum on the outer loop that gets the subsequent chunks. I chose not to post my code so far, because I don't think it's good, and I don't want anyone to feel they should build on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think a LINQ solution will be appropriate for your scenario. I would prefer using a for-loop, comparing the contents of each line in your text file accordingly.

---

Psuedocode:

```
string previousStudentID = null;
List<...> chunk = new List<...>();
foreach (string line in file)
{
    string studentID = // parse studentID from line

    if (studentID != previousStudentID && chunk.Count > 5)
    {
        // add header to beginning of chunk
        // load chunk to API

        chunk.Clear(); // clear/create a new chunk
    }

    // add line to chunk

    previousStudentID = studentID;
}

// load remaining header/chunk to API, if necessary
```

Comment: This works very well, has the advantage of being simple and you've worked in loading the data to the API from memory. I will choose a best answer once I've run through @NetMage answer. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to group by student ID isn't very efficient, so it seemed better to process during lines.

```
public class TestRecord {
    public string line;
    public string StudentID;

    public TestRecord(string _line) {
        line = _line;
        StudentID = Regex.Split(line, @"\s+")[0];
    }
}

public IEnumerable<TestRecord> ReadRecords(string filename) {
    var fileInput = File.ReadLines(filename);

    foreach (var line in fileInput)
        yield return new TestRecord(line);
}

void Main() {
    var filePath = @"file folder\";
    var recordInput = ReadRecords($"{filePath}students.txt");
    var inputEnumerator = recordInput.GetEnumerator();

    // get header line
    inputEnumerator.MoveNext();
    var headerLine = inputEnumerator.Current.line;
    inputEnumerator.MoveNext();

    var chunkSize = 5;

    var outFileCount = 0;
    var chunkSoFar = 0;
    StreamWriter outFile = null;
    bool moreInput;
    do {
        if (chunkSoFar >= chunkSize || chunkSoFar == 0) { // start new chunk
            outFile?.Close();
            outFile = new StreamWriter($"{filePath}chunk{++outFileCount:D4}.txt".Dump());
            outFile.WriteLine(headerLine.Dump());
            chunkSoFar = 0;
        }
        string curStudentID = inputEnumerator.Current.StudentID;
        do {
            outFile.WriteLine(inputEnumerator.Current.line.Dump());
            ++chunkSoFar;
        } while ((moreInput = inputEnumerator.MoveNext()) && inputEnumerator.Current.StudentID == curStudentID);
    } while (moreInput);
    outFile.Close();
}
```